# Display all paragraphs of a scraped HTML div in Django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, django-templates

So I have a scraped HTML div from a news website. Which is this piece of HTML:

```html
<div class="cn-content">

<figure><img src="https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/1/5ca/71a090479e.jpg" sizes="(min-width: 640px) 720px, 100vw" srcset="https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/1/5ca/71a090479e.jpg 300w, https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/2/5ca/71a090479e.jpg 600w, https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/3/5ca/71a090479e.jpg 720w, https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/4/5ca/71a090479e.jpg 900w, https://cimg.co/w/articles-attachments/0/5ca/71a090479e.jpg 1337w" alt="OKEx Announced its First Token Sale via IEO 101" class="content-img"><figcaption>Source: iStock/baona</figcaption></figure>
<p>Major cryptocurrency exchange <b>OKEx</b> has announced an initial exchange offering (IEO) for the <b>BLOC</b> token, on their newly-presented OK Jumpstart token sale platform. The sale marks the first such endeavor of the exchange, joining the likes of <a href="https://cryptonews.com/ext/binance/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">Binance </a>and <a href="https://cryptonews.com/ext/bittrex/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">Bittrex </a>in the so-called killer app club.</p>
<p>The token in question is BLOC, native to the <b>Blockcloud</b> blockchain, and the sale is set to start at AM 12:00 UTC on April 10th. “Combining the advantages of blockchain and Future Internet technology, it reconstructs the technology layers below where current blockchain networks and Internet applications operate,” explains the project’s website. In short, it is a blockchain-based TCP/IP architecture, where TCP/IP is a suite of communication protocols used to interconnect network devices on the internet. </p>
<p>The token sale uses a subscription + allotment approach. Users will have a timeframe of 30 minutes to subscribe, and allotment will be based on the amount of the exchange’s native <a href="https://cryptonews.com/coins/okb/">OKB tokens</a> they hold over a seven-day period. The minimum threshold for a subscription is 500 OKB tokens (USD 1,145) held for those seven consecutive days, or buying in 3,500 OKB tokens on the last day - but to have their subscription guaranteed, users need to hold at least 2,500 OKB tokens daily or buy 17,500 OKB tokens on the final day before snapshot time.</p>
<p>The snapshots, which will be used to prove the users’ eligibility for participation, will be taken every day at AM 10:00 UTC, starting seven days before the token sale day. Then, users get their individual allotment coefficients based on the sum of OKB holdings in the moment of those snapshots. Users will have their individual subscription amounts in OKB locked up, and receive tokens based on a formula available on the OKEx blog. This formula bases the token allotment on both how many tokens users held during this period, as well as the amount of OKB they locked in as their subscription. </p>
<p>This move lets OKEx join the club of exchanges offering fundraising services. The latest example was Bittrex, where the token sale of <b>VeriBlock</b> tokens took a <a href="https://cryptonews.com/news/bittrex-beats-binance-in-selling-out-tokens-at-lightning-spe-3633.htm">mere 10 seconds</a>, beating even Binance’s speed of 22 seconds for the <b><a href="https://cryptonews.com/coins/fetch-ai/">Fetch.AI</a></b> token. Binance’s co-founder and CEO Changpeng Zhao coined the term “killer app” back in February, when he said in an interview that he views exchange-based fundraising as the next killer app.</p>
        </div>
```

So inside my models I defined a property to clean up this HTML so I only display the paragraph text, like so:

```
@property
def description_clean(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.description)
    description = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"cn-content"})
    for item in description:
        return item.find('p').text
```

However this is only rendering the first paragraph when I use this inside a template with `{{ post.description_clean }}`

The output is:

> Major cryptocurrency exchange OKEx has announced an initial exchange offering (IEO) for the BLOC token, on their newly-presented OK Jumpstart token sale platform. The sale marks the first such endeavor of the exchange, joining the likes of Binance and Bittrex in the so-called killer app club.

Why do the other paragraphs not get rendered because I loop over it right?

Comment: `return` exits the function and returns some value, for loop does not execute after first loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

```
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "cn-content"})
paragraphs = main_div.find_all('p')
for p in paragraphs:
    # save p text
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the `div` tags, you did not loop over all the `p` tags.
Update your code to this:

```
@property
def description_clean(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.description)
    description = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"cn-content"})
    p_tags = []  # result list
    for item in description:
        individual_p_tags = []  # preserve each individual "div"
        for p in item.find_all('p'):  # loop over all the "p" tags in each "div"
            individual_p_tags.append(p.text)  # append to a temp list
        p_tags.append("\n".join(individual_p_tags)) # convert the list to a string and append to the result list
    return p_tags  # this is a list of strings
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same output

Comment: Yaaayy this worked. However is there any way to preserve the different paragraphs? Because of the white lines. Right now everything is concentated after each other and it is quite unreadable.

Comment: updated the answer.. the code will now return a list of strings for each div

Comment: Appreciate the help but I feel like it is still not what I wanted.. Right now when I use `{% for p in post.description_clean %}
        <p class="mtb-15">{{ p }}</p>
        {% endfor %}`  I just get the entire item. I want to loop over every paragraph in the template so I can use the class="mtb-15" on it.

Comment: I think then https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673488/4186008 is the best solution in this case. you will have all the paragraphs, just append `p.text` to a list and return this list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a list of the paragraphs

```
description = [item.text for item in soup.select('div.cn-content')]
```

and then

```
return description
```